# Android -Images in Drawable Folder Appear Blurry

Tags: android, image, kotlin, imageview

I'm testing this in the Emulator Pixel 4, API 33.

I added some 100x100 png images to the `drawable` folder but they all come out blurry. I copied and pasted each one into the folder. I've tried `android:src="drawable/..."`, `android:background="drawable/..."`, `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and different combinations of each but the image always comes out blurry. I even tried CircleImageView, Glide, and Picasso, but the blur is still there. This happens with all of my images except the ones in the BottomNavigationView

Here is an example of one of them:

[image]

Here it is the bottom navigationView but not as blurry. I'm assuming because it's shrunk down.

[image]

In iOS they use 1x, 2x, 3x images. I drop the above 100x100 image into a program like https://hotpot.ai/blog/ios-1x-2x-3x-generator, and afterwards once I drag the images into the Assets folder, I don't have to worry about the blur (I have 3 versions of it). In iOS this same 100x100 image appears **sharp**

Is the issue me copying and pasting the image into the drawables folder but instead I need `1x, 1.5x, 2x, 3x, and 4x` versions of the image? Btw I'm still learning Android.

Example code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="drawable/profile_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            .../>
        <TextView

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="drawable/profile_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" // I've tried multiple scaleTypes 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            .../>
        <TextView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the issue me copying and pasting the image into the drawables folder but instead I need 1x, 1.5x, 2x, 3x, and 4x versions of the image?

Yes. Use `res/drawable/` at most for vector drawables and other XML-defined drawables. For bitmaps, use:

- `res/drawable-mdpi/` (1x)
- `res/drawable-hdpi/` (1.5x)
- `res/drawable-xhdpi/` (2x)
- `res/drawable-xxhdpi/`(3x)
- `res/drawable-xxxhdpi/` (4x)

This is covered more in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp).

Comment: Thanks for this answer!!! I just went to https://hotpot.ai/icon-resizer, toggled on `Android Image`, and dropped in my image. It returned `hdpi.png`, `ldpi.png`, `mdpi.png`,  `xhdpi.png`, `xxhdpi.png`, and `xxxhdpi.png`, what am I supposed to do from here? Do I prefix the image name `profile_icon` to each as in `profile_icon_hdpi.png` and then drop them all into the `res/drawable` folder? I'm a little lost because in iOS the prefix name is automatically added as in `profile_icon@1x` etc. Then I drop all 3 of them into Assets and I'm done.

Comment: @LanceSamaria: No, you create directories like `res/drawable-mdpi/`, as peers of `res/drawable/`. You need to name the images the same (e.g., `profile_icon.png`) and have the one with the proper density in the proper directory (e.g., the `hdpi` image in `res/drawable-hdpi/`).

Comment: Ok thanks. You sent me in the right direction. I'm going to Google it from here. MUCH RESPECT TO YOU! Cheers!!!